# Why does console.log(buffer) give me a hexadecimal list?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
buffer = new Buffer 100
buffer[i] = i for i in [0..99]
console.log buffer
```

which compiles to

```
  var buffer, i;
  buffer = new Buffer(100);
  for (i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    buffer[i] = i;
  }
  console.log(buffer);
```

When I run it with node, I get the following output:

```
$ coffee exercise1
<Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f 60 61 62 63>
```

instead of 0 to 99. Why is that?

Comment: It does output 0..99, the numbers are just shown in hex.  Why? Because that is the way the designer of `Buffer` wanted buffers to render as strings.  Usually we like to see bytes in hex.

Comment: Answer it for the win =)

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that this is a Node issue, not a CoffeeScript one. CoffeeScript doesn't go in and mess with the way `console.log` or `Buffer` works; it just gives you JavaScript.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ray nailed it in his comment. See the [Buffer documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html); you have to specify an `encoding` argument (you probably want `'utf8'`) on a Buffer's `toString`.

```
// coffeescript
console.log buffer.toString 'utf8'
// javascript
console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'));
```

Comment: Related question, is there a way to get the output that you see when you do `console.log(buffer)` in any other way? E.g. I want to log that representation, but when I do something like `console.log('Buffer =`, buffer.toString('hex'))` it outputs the buffer data concatenated in a long hex string, not in the <Buffer xx xx xx> format.

Comment: The `console.log` method uses util.inspect to format its arguments, so you can do this ```const util = require('util'); console.log('I want to show a buffer here '+util.inspect(buf)+' in the middle of this string')```